# keyboard not working in grub after power off. Restart or short power cycle works fine

Tags: boot, grub2, keyboard

I recently installed Xubuntu 16.0.4.2 on a Lenovo ideapad 17ISK and now have the problem that the keyboard is not working in grub on power on.
After a restart or when I power off and very shortly afterwards power on again it works fine!
I read lots of topics covering USB keyboard not working, but this is the builtin laptop keyboard. I haven't tried with an external keyboard since that is not an option.
The system is dual boot with Windwos 10.

Any ideas?

Cheers,
bob

Comment: So the keyboard comes alive after the OS finishes booting?

Comment: Yes, after the OS is up, all is fine and I can use the keyboard. It also works in BIOS or Boot Menu, but I used the "rescue-button" to access BIOS. Will try if hitting F12 gets me to the BIOS as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Grub is unable to properly initialize your keyboard. But once Linux booted, it's properly initialized and can be used by Grub. That is indeed strange. Are you sure it is not a USB keyboard? That is, even though it is internal, it might be on an internal USB bus (you can check with `lsusb`, eventually add `-v` for more details).

Maybe it is enough to update your BIOS? (Seems the Y700 can only do that from Windows).

If this persists after a BIOS update, you might be better of opening a bug at Ubuntu or Grub. But of course someone here might have a Y700-17ISK (I don't) and a better idea/answer.

Comment: (I would actually just have commented/asked if you updated the BIOS, but below 50 reputation that's not possible - so here is a semi-helpful answer instead)

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure about USB-keyboard, will check that.

Comment: not sure, but lsusb -v shows no entry saying keyboard. One said "Miscellanous", all others were clearly other things (root hub, camer,...) so I think it is not usb.

Comment: Ahh, too bad. Only thing I can think of is your BIOS then. Sorry :(

Comment: Since WIN10 is (now freshly) installed, I'll give it a try...

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I did a fresh install of both Windows 10 and Xubuntu.

At first it worked just as it should but after re-enabling Windows 10 "fast startup" the keyboard stopped responding in grub after having switched off the laptop for more than a few seconds.

Disabling fast boot got it back to normal!
Seems like I have found the culprit :)